# why the iterators can't refer to the container they belong to when container calls assign?

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks

```
string s="zhangzhizhong";
s.assign(s.begin()+2, s.end()-2);
string is correct!
vector<int> ivec{0,1,2,3,4,5}; 
ivec.assign(ivec.begin()+1, ivec.end()-1); 
vector is also correct!!!
```

The above code is correct, but what is written in the book is that the iterators can't refer to the container they belong to when container calls `assign()`.

Comment: What's the question? What book?

Comment: No that's definitely not correct.

Comment: why? I run the above code in Codeblocks there is no error.

Comment: It exhibits undefined behavior. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior. [Making demons fly out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) is another.

Answer (score 3):

This is illegal for sequential containers, like `vector` or `deque`.

> **[sequence.reqmts]/4** Table 100
>
> `a.assign(i,j)` pre: `i`, `j` are not iterators into `a`

But I believe it's explicitly made valid for `std::string`:

> **[string::assign]/20**
>
> ```
> template<class InputIterator>
> basic_string& assign(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
> ```
>
> *Effects*: Equivalent to `assign(basic_string(first, last))`.

The standard requires that the implementation make a copy of the sequence before performing the assignment (or at least, behave as if it does). There is no requirement I can see that iterators not point into the string being assigned.

I'm not sure why it doesn't work this way for containers, but if I had to guess, I'd say it's precisely to avoid forcing the implementation to make extra copies.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I looked on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/assign/, which claims iterators are being invalidated. Obviously the standard takes precedence...

Comment: @H.Guijt That's a post-condition on `assign()`, not a precondition on its arguments.